# Finding $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log_{1.1}x}{x}$ analytically

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log_{1.1}x}{x}$$

I can solve this easily by generating the graph with my calculator, but is there is a way to do this analytically?

Comment: There are several ways this problem can be tackled. Some are more advanced than others. It would be helpful if you told us how much you already know about limits, and calculus in general.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Honestly, not much. So far whenever I had to find limits I would just get the graph on the calculator. I don't really know how to solve them analitically

Comment: Try using the change of base formula and basic facts about the natural log function.

Comment: @ncmathsadist I get $\frac{\frac{\log(x)}{\log(1.1)}}{x} = \frac{\log(x)}{\log(1.1^x)} = \log_{1.1^x}(x) = ???$. What do I do next?

Answer (score 1):

Since the limit of both the top and bottom is $\infty$ alone, l'hopital's rule gives us
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log_{1.1} x}{x}
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{(\ln 1.1) x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(1/x)}{(\ln 1.1)} \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Actually, the limit numerator is not required to be infinity to apply LHR.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you for that footnote and reminder!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And to add to the conversation, the limit of the numerator need not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: L'hospitale's rule ! . Have you learned this formula yet?

Comment: No I haven't, but I'll look into it.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is not the alpha and omega of limits computing!

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\ln(x)-\sqrt{x}$

we have $g(1)=0$ and

$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{2x}(2-\sqrt{x})$$

$g$ is decreasing at $[4,+\infty)$

thus

$$\forall x\geq 4  \;\;0<\frac{\log_{1.1}(x)}{x}\leq \frac{1}{\ln(1.1)\sqrt{x}}$$

and squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition: $\;\log_{1.1}x=\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln 1.1}$, so
$$\frac{\log_{1.1}x}{x}=\frac 1{\ln 1.1}\dfrac{\ln x}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to+\infty]{}\frac 1{\ln 1.1}\cdot 0=0.$$

Comment: That's not helpful if OP doesn't know $$\dfrac{\ln x}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to+\infty]{} 0$$

Comment: This depends on OP is supposed to know. However this limit is taught in high school.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on elementary tools only.  To that end, we begin with the following primer.
>
> **PRIMER:  BOUNDS FOR THE LOGARITHM FUNCTION**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x}{x-1}\le \log(x)\le x-1} \tag 1$$
>
> for $x<1$.

---

Now, we note that $\log_{1.1}(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(1.1)}$.  In addition, we note that for any number $a$, we have $\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$.

Using $(1)$, we have for $a>0$,

$$\frac{x^{-1}-x^{-(a+1)}}{a}\le \frac{\log(x)}{x}\le \frac{x^{a-1}-x^{-1}}{a} \tag 2$$

Surely, $(2)$ is valid for $0<a<1$.  Then, applying the squeeze theorem to $(2)$ with $0<a<1$ (e.g., $a=1/2$) yields the coveted limit

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log_{1.1}(x)}{x}=0}$$

and we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark